# SQL Query to Show Parents of Elements Considering Hierarchy Rules

Tags: sql, mysql

[modules table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ITwz.png)

```sql
--
-- Table structure for table `groups`
--    
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `file` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pere` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `groups`
--

INSERT INTO `groups` (`file`, `pere`) VALUES
('AM1001', 'AM100'),
('AM1101', 'AM1001'),
('AM1201', 'AM1001'),
('AM1301', 'AM1001'),
('AM1401', 'AM1001'),
('AM1501', 'AM1001'),
('AM1601', 'AM1001'),
('AM1701', 'AM1001'),
('AM1801', 'AM1001'),
('AR1001', 'AR1000'),
('AR1101', 'AR1001'),
('AR1201', 'AR1001'),
('AR1301', 'AR1001'),
('AR1401', 'AR1001'),
('AR1501', 'AR1001'),
('AR1601', 'AR1001'),
('AR1701', 'AR1001'),
('AR1801', 'AR1001'),
('AM1711', 'AM1701'),
('AM1712', 'AM1701'),
('AR1711', 'AR1701'),
('AR1712', 'AR1701'),
('AM2101', 'AM2001'),
('AM2001', 'AM2000'),
('AM2221', 'AM2201'),
('AM2211', 'AM2201');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `modules`
--

CREATE TABLE `modules` (
  `code` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `modules`
--

INSERT INTO `modules` (`code`, `nom`, `type`) VALUES
('AM1001', 'SM01', 'SM01'),
('AM1101', 'module1', 'MOD'),
('AM1201', 'module2', 'MOD'),
('AM1301', 'module3', 'MOD'),
('AM1401', 'module4', 'MOD'),
('AM1501', 'module5', 'MOD'),
('AM1601', 'module6', 'MOD'),
('AM1701', 'module7', 'MOD'),
('AM1801', 'module8', 'MOD'),
('AR1001', 'SM01', 'SM01'),
('AR1101', 'moduleR1', 'MOD'),
('AR1201', 'moduleR2', 'MOD'),
('AR1301', 'moduleR3', 'MOD'),
('AR1401', 'moduleR4', 'MOD'),
('AR1501', 'moduleR5', 'MOD'),
('AR1601', 'moduleR6', 'MOD'),
('AR1701', 'moduleR7', 'MOD'),
('AR1801', 'moduleR8', 'MOD'),
('AM1711', 'elm1', 'EM'),
('AM1712', 'elm2', 'EM'),
('AR1711', 'elmR1', 'EM'),
('AR1712', 'elmR2', 'EM'),
('AM2001', 'SM02', 'SM02'),
('AM2101', 'moduleS2 1', 'MOD'),
('AM2211', 'elm M S2', 'EM'),
('AM2121', 'elm S2 2', 'EM');
```

[groups table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct0Wk.png)

i want from 2 table to get all MOD and EM with own SM But the problem relation is bettwen SM and MOD OR MOD AND EM no relation direct bettwen SM AND EM
resultat like that

This scenario is relevant for various data management situations involving hierarchical relationships, where you need to trace ancestry despite indirect connections.

[resultat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYOY.png)

Comment: i use mysql  on this case

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute and **NOT** as images); the expected output for your sample data (again as text formatted using markdown and not as an image); and your attempt at a solution to the problem.